# What's the correct way to compute a confusion matrix for object detection?

Tags: python, object-detection, confusion-matrix

I am trying to compute a confusion matrix for my object detection model. However, I seem to stumble across some pitfalls. My current approach is to compare each predicted box with each ground truth box. If they have an IoU > some threshold, I insert the predictions into the confusion matrix. After the insertion, I delete the element in the predictions list and move on to the next element.

Because I also want the misclassified proposals to be inserted in the confusion matrix, I treat the elements with IoU lower than the threshold as confusion with the background. My current implementation looks like this:

```
def insert_into_conf_m(true_labels, predicted_labels, true_boxes, predicted_boxes):
    matched_gts = []
    for i in range(len(true_labels)):
        j = 0
        while len(predicted_labels) != 0:
            if j >= len(predicted_boxes):
                break
            if bb_intersection_over_union(true_boxes[i], predicted_boxes[j]) >= 0.7:
                conf_m[true_labels[i]][predicted_labels[j]] += 1
                del predicted_boxes[j]
                del predicted_labels[j]
            else:
                j += 1
        matched_gts.append(true_labels[i])
        if len(predicted_labels) == 0:
            break
    # if there are ground-truth boxes that are not matched by any proposal
    # they are treated as if the model classified them as background
    if len(true_labels) > len(matched_gts):
        true_labels = [i for i in true_labels if not i in matched_gts or matched_gts.remove(i)]
        for i in range(len(true_labels)):
            conf_m[true_labels[i]][0] += 1

    # all detections that have no IoU with any groundtruth box are treated
    # as if the groundtruth label for this region was Background (0)
    if len(predicted_labels) != 0:
        for j in range(len(predicted_labels)):
            conf_m[0][predicted_labels[j]] += 1
```

The row-normalized matrix looks like this:

```
[0.0, 0.36, 0.34, 0.30]
[0.0, 0.29, 0.30, 0.41]
[0.0, 0.20, 0.47, 0.33]
[0.0, 0.23, 0.19, 0.58]
```

Is there a better way to generate the confusion matrix for an object detection system? Or any other metric that is more suitable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here is a script](https://github.com/svpino/tf_object_detection_cm) to compute the confusion matrix from the detections.record file generated by the TensorFlow Object Detection API. [Here is the article](https://www.shiftedup.com/2018/10/10/confusion-matrix-in-object-detection-api-with-tensorflow) explaining how this script works.

In summary, here is the outline of the algorithm from the article:

> 1. For each detection record, the algorithm extracts from the input file the ground-truth boxes and classes, along with the detected
>      boxes, classes, and scores.
> 2. Only detections with a score greater or equal than 0.5 are considered. Anything that’s under this value is discarded.
> 3. For each ground-truth box, the algorithm generates the IoU (Intersection over Union) with every detected box. A match is found if
>      both boxes have an IoU greater or equal than 0.5.
> 4. The list of matches is pruned to remove duplicates (ground-truth boxes that match with more than one detection box or vice versa). If
>      there are duplicates, the best match (greater IoU) is always selected.
> 5. The confusion matrix is updated to reflect the resulting matches between ground-truth and detections.
> 6. Objects that are part of the ground-truth but weren’t detected are counted in the last column of the matrix (in the row corresponding to
>      the ground-truth class). Objects that were detected but aren’t part of
>      the confusion matrix are counted in the last row of the matrix (in the
>      column corresponding to the detected class).

You can also take a look [at the script](https://github.com/svpino/tf_object_detection_cm/blob/master/confusion_matrix.py) for more information.

Comment: Can you please explain how to calculate the number of True positives, False positives, False negatives and True negatives for each class using the script provided

Comment: @svpino In step 4 shouldn't the best Score be used (Non-max-suppression) instead of the best IoU?