# Tensorflow Object Detection API: how to find out false positives, false negatives, true positives?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am using [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) to finetune a pretrained model from [the model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) for custom object detection. Once my model is converged I use [`eval_util.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/eval_util.py) with `EvalConfig.metrics_set='open_images_V2_detection_metrics'` to obtain the `mAP`(and class-specific `AP`s) which lets me measure the quality of my model.

But just `mAP` is not enough for my purposes. For better analysis, I want to know the exact breakdown of my model's results into false positives, false negatives and true positives. I wish to be able to see this breakdown in terms of actual test images - that is, I want to see my test images being physically divided into those three groups, automatically.

How can I do that?

I tried searching through Tensorflow's offical documentation and, to some extent, through the relevant python files on github, but I haven't found a way yet.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I ran into this same problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the correct way to compute a confusion matrix for object detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46110545/whats-the-correct-way-to-compute-a-confusion-matrix-for-object-detection)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a confusion matrix. 
Take a look at this link:
[Tensorflow Confusion Matrix](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/confusion_matrix)

You can basically evaluate your predictions with this function.

Answer (score 0):

We also meet this problem. Now we find some clues in object_detection/utils/metrics.py. Maybe you can have a try. Hope you can share your solutions!